# StoreKit2 showManageSubscriptions(in:) close button does not work

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, storekit

I use the new StoreKit2 method to display the AppStore subscription management window. For some reason, the close button does not work. And the opening of the window is accompanied by a strange animation - the modal display should capture my current window, but it captures a strange gray area.
This is an empty project, with a single ViewController. Xcode 13.3.1

```
@objc func testFunc() {

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first {
        Task {
            do {
                try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[showManageSubscriptions(in:) close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahvyy.png)

[Strange grey area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogr82.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the results of our tests, **there may be a bug for close button to showManageSubscriptions(in:) in iOS 15.3 and 15.3.1**. Only can user **swipe down** to close the page when using this system version.**Bug is fixed in iOS 15.3.2**.